# Decrypt the message by factoring n or without factoring n in RSA

Tags: cryptography, rsa, prime-factoring

An RSAcryptosystem has public key n = 18721 and e = 25. Messages are encrypted crypted one letter at a time, converting letters to numbers by A = 2, B = 3 c _ 27. Oscar intercepts the message "365, 18242, 4845, 18242, 17173, 16;134:"" from Alice to Bob.

(la) Decrypt the message by factorizing n.

(lb) Decrypt the message assuming that you cannot factorize n.

can any body teach me too step by step how to decrypt message and also what is p&q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions can be answered by reading the wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) on RSA.

## 1a

When you factor **n**, you find integers **p** and **q** such that **n = p * q**. You calculate **Y = (p - 1)(q - 1)**. Then you can find the private key exponent **d**, which is calculated as **d = 1/e mod Y**.

To decrypt one of the values **c** in the intercepted message, you simply calculate **m = c^d mod n**, where **m** is the decrypted message. This works because **(m^e)^d mod n** is equal to 1.

I'll leave the actual calculations to you. If you get stuck, the wiki page has some good examples.

## 1b

If you cannot factorize **n**, then you can't decrypt the message. If it were possible to decrypt the message using only the public key **(n,e)**, then why would anyone use RSA?

Comment: Nobody has proven in the standard model that if you cannot factorise then you cannot decrypt, however it is believed to be true and random oracle assumptions support that if proper padding such as OAEP is used.

Comment: i did it by self last day and it was similar to your approach

Answer (score 1):

**1a.** is answered correctly by the upvoted answer

**1b.**
Knowing that each message chunk is only 1 character Oscar can encrypt each character of the alphabet with the same e and n and compare them.

a = 2^25 mod 18721  = 6400

b = 3^25 mod 18721  = 18718

c = 4^25 mod 18721  = 17173
...

The upvoted answer is true for encryptions of more than one character but not the case when each character is individually encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

For the 1b approach the phrase [Rainbow Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) might be revealing (though intentionally somewhat over-specific/misleading).

It was pretty fun.  I'll tell you that your 2nd and 4th letters are `'E'`; and that I'm pretty sure you typoed the last value (`134`).  It's either `1375` (which makes the most sense to me) or `13444` (the closest string match, and also sort of makes sense).

@bkjvbx's answer is right in the case of RSA as used in the wild; but since this (presumably) homework assignment is using raw RSA on remarkably scoped inputs it's a whole different beast.